# create a template widget in Dojo

Tags: templates, dojo, widget

Hi I'm a beginner to learn Dojo. 
I want some dojo examples for creating widget with template in Dojo.

I tried this,

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body, html { font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif; font-size:90%; }
    </style>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var url = location.href; 
        var current_path = url.substring(0,url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        var dojoConfig = {
            parseOnLoad: true,
            debug: true         };
    </script>
    <script>
        dojo.require('dijit._WidgetBase');
    dojo.require('dijit._Templated');
        dojo.addOnLoad(function() {

    dojo.declare('MyForm',[dijit._WidgetBase,dijit._Templated],{

                templatePath: dojo.moduleUrl("test.html")
            });
        });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"/>
</head>

<body class="claro">
</body>
```

please help me

Comment: Where exactly should we help you? If you are new to dojo have a look at the Tutorials here : http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/ They give you a good Point to start with dojo.

Comment: how to create a template widget

Comment: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/recipes/custom_widget/ This one gives a good view into creating template widgets and this two does too : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/quickstart/writingWidgets.html and http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2014/02/13/creating-dojo-widgets-with-inline-templates-2/

Comment: What problems are you having?  What have you tried so far?